# XHTML & IE6 overflow:hidden problem

Tags: xhtml, internet-explorer-6, overflow, hidden

How can I get this CSS declaration to work in IE6 please?

`#mask{width:725px;height:495px;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;}`

The problem is the content which is much larger than 725px and exactly 495px (much like a horizontal scrolling thingy) does not get hidden in IE6.

**Edit:**
1. The background images of the hidden divs shows.
2. I am also using [Twin-Helix PNG Fix 2.0 Alpha](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/).

Thank you.

Comment: you may have to add a parent div to the mask, then give it position:relative - it's an IE6-only issue.

Comment: Hi, I tried that just now and it didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: Or did you mean the mask div by "give it position:relative". I'll give it a go as well.

Comment: Which doc type are you using?

Comment: What is the content which isn't hidden, images? Background image? Remove the PNG Fix script to see if something happens (I tried your css/html and it worked here)

Comment: Background images. Good idea, I'll remove that and see if they go away. Thanks.

Comment: That didn't work, however, jpea's idea worked. I had initially set position relative for the #mask parent, however setting it to the #mask itself worked. Thank you both. Jpea, you should make your comment into an answer so I can mark it accordingly.

Comment: I've written up an answer and also detailed what's triggering the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be happening because you have relatively positioned elements inside your `#mask` container.

This is due to a bug where relatively positioned children are not correctly clipped and hidden for a parent element with `overflow: hidden` applied in Internet Explorer 6 and 7. The same problem [also exists for `overflow: auto`](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/) and undoubtedly `overflow: scroll` as well.

It can be fixed [by also applying `position: relative` to the element you are setting the overflow on](http://haslayout.net/css/Relative-Overflow-Failure-Bug).